# Formula in Python not working as expected

Tags: python

I'm trying to have this function work, but i'm not getting the results expected. I fully believe it because I'm new to Python.... Here is my code:

```
waterLevel = (-(25/144) * sensorValue) + (14725/72) ;
```

And here is the equation:

```
y=-25x/144 + 14725/72
```

So when `x=1178` then `y=0` (y=waterLevel) and when `x=602` then `y=100`.

I am getting this, when `x=1178` then `y=204`.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update** This is a different question because I didn't know it was floating point python nonsense .... just that my math wasn't working. Just because the answer is the same doesn't mean it is a duplicate.  ;)

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: 2.7 ..................

Comment: waterLevel = (-(25/144.) * sensorValue) + (14725/72.)

Comment: `-(25/144) = 0` You need to make one of them floats

Comment: Incidentally you don't need to end your lines with semi-colons in Python :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are falling foul of integer division as opposed to float division.

In Python 2.x `25/144` will produce integer division which means it will result in 0.

If you're going to be dealing with floating point numbers then you should use floating point numbers, i.e. `25.0/144.0`.

In Python 3.x the division of integers will default to returning the floating point value and instead you must explicitly choose integer division using `//`. If you would like this behaviour in Python 2 then use `from __future__ import division` at the top of your script (thanks to jwodder for the comment).

Comment: Alternatively, put `from __future__ import division` at the top of the script.

Comment: Thanks. I am brand new to this language and have to use it for some projects at work...  in 10 minutes you get a checkmark

Answer (score 0):

Use `floats` instead of `ints`

```
waterLevel = (-(25.0/144.0) * sensorValue) + (14725.0/72.0)
```

By the way, there is an adicional parethesis in the beginning of the equation, is it a typo?

Comment: @Magnum I was hoping to be more clear in my intentions so that when others view my code they know exactly what I mean.